# Manipulating variable containing command

Tags: footnotes, theorems, ntheorem

Here's a MWE of my issue

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[framed,thmmarks,thref, hyperref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\test}{
\ifcsname theoremname\endcsname
    \wlog{\theoremname}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[my theorem\footnotemark]
\test
    asdf
\end{theorem}\footnotetext{asdf}

\end{document}
```

I would like to retrieve the "my theorem" string. The problem is that `\theoremname` contains also the `\footnotemark`, hence trying to naively access it resulted in a bunch of errors like "\@item doesn't match its definition" and so on.

I would be happy both in case I could replace the old `\theoremname` with a new one without the `\footnotemark` or (in probably more flexible way) create within `\test` a new variable with the string I need.

Comment: You could perhaps disable `footnotemark` with `\let\footnotemark\relax` at the start of `\test`.  Also you need a `%` in the line `\newcommand{\test}{%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not going to require a list of theorems - `\listtheorems{theorem}` - you can merely remove the functionality of `\footnotemark` within `\test` by `\let`ting it to `\relax` *temporarily*:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framed,thmmarks,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newcommand{\test}{\begingroup
  \ifcsname theoremname\endcsname% If theorem name exists:
    \let\footnotemark\relax% Remove \footnotemark functionality
    \theoremname% Set theorem name
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[my theorem\footnotemark]
  \test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use the `\theoremname` as part of a `\label`, perhaps the following will work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framed,thmmarks,thref,hyperref]{ntheorem}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labeltheorem}[1]{\begingroup
  \ifcsname theoremname\endcsname% If theorem name exists:
    \def\footnotemark{}% Remove \footnotemark functionality
    \edef\@currentlabel{\theoremname}% Set theorem name
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[my theorem\footnotemark]
  \labeltheorem{test}asdf
\end{theorem}

See \ref{test}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What if I want to set a label with the name of the theorem (after removing the footnote mark)? I know this is a bit far from the OP, but I was hoping accessing the name would have been enough. I put the `\newcommand` within a `\makeatletter`,`\makeatother` pair and after the "relax" line I wrote 
`\def\@currentlabel{\theoremname}` 
`\label{testlabel}`
The idea is that when I `\ref{testlabel}` I should see the name of the theorem, but if I have a footnote mark this seems not to work, and the "relax" trick doesn't seem to help. However thanks, I'll accept and +1 anyway!

Comment: @Saphrosit: See the updated answer.